# Postpone installation in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, msdn

I would like to create WiX installer that behaves like following:
- if it finds out that instance of program is already installed and currently running it should postpone installation till next reboot.

How can this be achieved with WiX?

After research that I have done i see following possibility:
- create custom action and use `MoveFileEx` with option `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` if instance of program is running

Is this a good approach or maybe another solution should be used?

**Update 1**

Additional info that is a small problem. Function `::MoveFileEx'` requires permission to access registry to store value.

> If the dwFlags parameter specifies MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT, MoveFileEx fails if it cannot access the registry. The function stores the locations of the files to be renamed at restart in the following registry value:

Comment: _After research that I have done i see following possibility ... _ it seems yoy've found a solution so whati is the problem?

Comment: @il_raffa i would like to know if it is ok. Maybe some WiX guru can tell me that there is possibility to do this in other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be trying to solve a problem that Windows has already solved.

(MoveFile seems irrelevant because Windows is installing these files, not you. In any case, Windows applies version rules and will not replace the existing version with a lower version (or the same file hash if unversioned) so you're already not following standard install rules. )

If you install the setup AND it needs to replace that file or any others then several things are possible:

1. It will show a files-in-use dialog. You can tell people to ignore it until they've finished with the program, then close it down by clicking "Retry" and they continue the install, no reboot required. The install is effectively suspended until they've finished with the program.
2. It will show a files-in-use dialog that you tell them to click Ignore on, so the install will continue, and at the end may ask for a reboot. The user postpones the reboot until they've finished with the program.
3. Suppress the files-in-use dialog and if a reboot is needed it will ask for one at the end, no files-in-use dialog shown, just a request for a reboot that the user does when they're ready.

The issue with you postponing something until the next reboot is that this typically requires an entry in the registry's RunOnce key or Program Menus Startup folder, and Windows doesn't want to run elevated programs automatically like that. Some AV software doesn't like writes to those locations either. So there may be issues with any solution requiring automatic running of elevated programs at reboot time.

Having said that, if you want to invent your own solution, I don't think it's really anything to do with WiX or Windows Installer. You write a program that checks to see if that other program is running. You start the install by running your program. If that other program isn't running, start your install and you're done. If that other program IS running you get your program in the Start menu's Startup folder or the RunOnce registry location, then it will restart after a reboot, then you again see if the program is running, and if not then start your install, and delete your Startup/RunOnce entry.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I would also like to clarify that this installer should run in multiuser environment. That's mean that few users can be logged to remote machine.. Admin runs remote installation and if installer figures out that one user works with application then installation should be postponed.

Comment: This is the main reason why I would like to add this functionality - not to disturb user work while silent installation is run by admin.

Comment: I am also aware of the policy that is responsible for showing dialog files in use or triggers reboot but I would like to avoid such behaviour to not disturb users work.